# Replace in multiple csv files while keeping the formatting

Tags: powershell, replace, formatting

I have a number  of csv files in which I need to replace a specific string. For this I already have a script to use in Powershell.
The problem is that almost in all the csv files, there are symbols or emojis that become questions marks (???) after I run the script.

What do I need to add to my script to keep my symbols and emojis ?

This is the code I use to replace a specific string in multiple csv files.

```
$DirPath = "C:\Users\Documents\*.csv"
Get-ChildItem $DirPath -Recurse |
ForEach-Object {
 (Get-Content $_).Replace('X','Y') |
 Set-Content $_
 }
```

As a result, the string is replaced but the symbols and emojis become ???

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Based on what solved the problem according to your feedback, you needed to use the
`-Encoding` parameter for both *reading* the input file and for *writing* the output file.

As an aside, I recommend using `-LiteralPath` with `Set-Content` and to *pipe* the input file-info object to `Get-Content`, so as to ensure that it binds to `-LiteralPath`, in order to avoid any possible issues with paths having wildcard characters.

```bash
$DirPath = 'C:\Users\Documents\*.csv'
Get-ChildItem $DirPath -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    ($_ | Get-Content -Encoding utf8).Replace('X', 'Y') |
        Set-Content -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Encoding utf8
}
```